# Making random numbers write on the page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that first selects a random number, and then print every number starting at 1 through the random number, on the page.

Basically, it should look something like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  twenty  five    26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  
36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50 51   52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  
70  71  72  73  74  seventy five    76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90 91   92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 
124 one hundred and twenty  five
```

Here's the function that I have so far. Currently, it's simply alerting a bunch of random numbers. How do I get it so that it doesn't alert the numbers, but writes them on the page itself? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
        function randomNumber() {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
            var english = {
            25 : "twenty five",
            75 : "seventy five",
            125 : "one hundred and twenty five"
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
            alert(num);

        }
        }

        document.getElementById('yourElement').onclick = randomNumber();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the event listener in a wrong way.

```
document.getElementById('yourElement').onclick = randomNumber();
```

When you use "onclick = randomNumber()" you are not setting the function randomNumber to onclick. Because you wrote "()" after the function, you are actually calling the function and the thing that is set to onclick is actually the return value of randomNumber, which is in your case "undefined".

This piece of code should do what you want.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function() {
            var english = {
                25 : 'twenty five'
                // and so on
            }

            function randomNumber() {
                var r = Math.round( Math.random() * 200 )
                return english[r] || r;
            }

            function writeRandomNumber() {
                this.innerHTML += randomNumber();
            }

            document.getElementById('yourElement').onclick = writeRandomNumber;
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use innerText, [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML), or [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) to set the text of an element:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").innerText += num;
```