# Writing numbers on a page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that writes a number sequence on the page from 1 to whatever number the random generator picks. If the numbers, 25, 75, or 125, are on the page, I want to change them to read twenty five, seventy five, and, one hundred and twenty five, respectively. Here's the code that I have right now. Do you have any suggestions? I'm stuck right now. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = randomNumber()

        var i = 0;
        var s = " ";
        function randomNumber() {
            var duck = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
            while (i < duck) {
                s += i + " ";
            }
            if ( duck = 25) {
                s+ = "twenty five";
            } else if ( duck = 75) {
                s+ = "seventy five";
            } else if ( duck = 125) {
                s+ = "one hundred and twenty five";
            }
            document.write(s);
        }

    </script>

<body style="background-color:yellow;">
    <div align="center">
        <div id="random">
            <input type="button" id="randomness" value="Click to Reveal!" onclick="randomNumber;">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Please explain.

Comment: What would one do with 125 ducks?

Comment: @JesseJ Possibly Homework?  Looks like a near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005619/making-random-numbers-write-on-the-page

Answer (score 0):

You are building your String without consulting your conditionals (that is, your conditional statements are outside of the loop that builds your String). You should change your `randomNumber` function to read:

```
function randomNumber() {
    var duck = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    while (i < duck) {
        if ( duck === 25) {
          s += "twenty five";
        } else if ( duck === 75) {
          s += "seventy five";
        } else if ( duck === 125) {
          s += "one hundred and twenty five";
        } else {
          s += i + " ";
        }
        i++
    }
    document.write(s);
}
```

Comment: First line outputting the number itselt should be moved to final else.